# Is this not misleading notation?

Tags: functions

If we have $f(x) = 2x$ for example we can write $y=f(x)$ to give $y=2x$ where $y$ is the value $f$ attains at the point $x$. Then we have $f(1) = 2$ and $f(2) = 4$, so $y=2$ and $y=4$, but also $y=y$, and its ridiculous to write $2=4$. Where is the flaw in my thinking?
Thanks in advance. (If you want to downvote, please let me know what I should improve in my question)

Comment: Yes, $y=f(x)$ (as it is traditionally used) is poor but common notation.

Comment: I am pretty good at maths for my age and this type of stuff just annoys me when I notice it.

Comment: $y=f(x)$ is used for the cartesian coordinate graph of the function. In all other cases, there is no "y", but only a function $f$.

Comment: I guess this issue stems from not teaching $f$ to be the function but rather $y$,

Comment: If we consider the graph then $y=f(x)$ is short for $\{(x,y)\mid y=f(x)\}.$

Comment: Better to say $y(1)=2$ and $y(2)=4$ since $y$ depends on $x$. You are making the symbol $y$ mean a fixed thing and an $x$ dependent thing simultaneously, which makes no sense.